# Updated to the latest Amazon linux but stil deprecated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I updated my beanstalk instance to the latest recommended version but the deprecated message is still there. What else do I need to update? What is deprecated?

[image]

Comment: What version of node are you using? It's probably the node version not the Linux version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using EB platform based on Amazon Linux 1. This is depricated. You have to **migrate** to EB platform based on **Amazon Linux 2**. This must be done manually as there are many differences between AL1 and AL2. General steps are explained in:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Kind of annoying since I implemented this beanstalk setup in the beginning of the year